# Unable to install GRUB in /dev/sda for dual boot with windows 7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, raid

Hello fellow Ubuntu users! Im very new to Ubuntu and im not too IT savy. I tried to install Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS on my my Windows 7 Alienware m17xr4 off of a LIVE USB.

Im trying to do a dual boot. I partitioned my HDD by going into *diskmgmt.msc* and using the windows partitioning tool. I booted Ubuntu (try Ubuntu) then proceeded to the installer and chose the option *Install along other operating systems,* which is kind of weird because I have no other operating systems on my system (maybe its the 38gbs of partitioned space for the factory Alienware Recovery). Anyhow, I get up to the part where its installing GRUB and then it gives me the error

```
executing 'grub-install/dev/sda'failed
This is a fatal error
```

I've seen the manual partitioning steps but my partition table looks nothing like what I see in the pictures. Mine shows up as RAID and has weird names that I cant make sense of for which one i need to partition to...

Please help me out here =)

Answer (score 1):

Please notice that installing an operating system is risky, so **backup** everything, that you cannot afford to lose before you start (or continue).

---

You should **use Windows to shrink the Windows partition** and create unallocated drive space. After that you should reboot Windows and let it adjust to the new size of its partition.

Then you should **boot from the Ubuntu boot drive and let the Ubuntu installer use the unallocated drive space for Ubuntu** (or if you know what to do, to use gparted and create partitions for Ubuntu, and then start the Ubuntu installer).

---

If you let Windows create partitions, it might (will probably) create dynamic partitions, which cannot be used by linux (and Ubuntu is a linux distro). If this is the case, you can remove this new partition (these new partitions), but be careful! Do not destroy what belongs to Windows.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/25693411/ is my bootlog info

Comment: @Dragos75, I think there is useful information in the boot-info log :-) `/dev/sda3 ends after the last sector of /dev/sda` indicates a damaged partition table, that might create problems. Maybe your observations in the original question about RAID is connected to this issue. *I have no experience of RAID, so I cannot help you, if there is RAID.* On the other hand, if there is not RAID, can you tell me about the second drive, `/dev/sdb`?

Comment: Well what i unded up doing was formating all drives and have only Ubuntu installed. O thought that would fix the problem but i still get the damm error...

Comment: Did you manage to turn off everything related to RAID? Maybe there is a setting in the BIOS/UEFI menus about it?